# print_control_identifiers() on a new window

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm trying to automate a process of sending data from software to equipment, right now I can do half of the process with this

```py
from pywinauto import Desktop, Application

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path="MGV6.exe")
app = app.window(best_match="MGV 6 Teste - Toledo do Brasil")

carga_menu = app.menu_select('Operações->Carga')
```

Then a new sub window opens and I can't figure out how to read the new window. I've also tried to use the `click()` instead of `menu_select` since they go to the same window, so would be something like use `bnt1.click()` (or `app.menu_select`) then `bnt2.click()` and the whole process would be done.

What I'm getting right now:

[image]

Comment: With `backend="uia"` new window is usually a child of main window. So try to find it in `app.dump_tree()`.

Comment: It dumps the information of the main window just like ` print_control_identifiers() ` it returns 
`child_window(title="Carga", control_type="Button")` , it's normal for the code to hang after switching from the main window to the child? I've realized that the code would hang until the child its gone

Comment: heres the dump_tree() if helps https://pastebin.com/e7H5vgaW

Comment: I was able to solve the problem with

`app = app.window(best_match="MGV 6 Teste - Toledo do Brasil")
app.child_window(title="Operações", control_type="MenuItem").click_input()
app.Carga.click_input()
app.Enviar.click_input()`

Comment: Great. Please post it as an answer and mark it accepted. It will show others that problem is solved and save their time.